# Change default stylesheet dir in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet

Would anyone know to change the default stylesheet directory /public/stylesheets to /public/css in rails 3?

I found a variable called 
`config.stylesheets_dir = '/css'`

This didn't work though.

I know I can do `<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/css/mystyle.css' %>` but I'm curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript and stylesheets paths were not fully dehardcoded in Rails 3.
To override these paths you need to monkey patch (with all consequences of that)
private method:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
    private
      def compute_stylesheet_paths(*args)
          expand_stylesheet_sources(*args).collect { |source| compute_public_path(source, 'stylesheets', 'css', false) }
      end
end
```

and additionaly this one if you use it:

```
  def stylesheet_path(source)
    compute_public_path(source, 'stylesheets', 'css')
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, here's what I'm doing. I create a wrapper `asset_tag` that can be used like this:

```
<%= asset_tag 'mystyle', :css %>
<%= asset_tag 'mycode', :js %>
```

And then I define it in the `application_helper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # here is where you define your paths
  # in this case, paths will be '/css/mystyle.css' and '/js/mycode.js'
  def asset_path(asset, type)
    return "/css/#{asset}.css" if type == :css
    return "/js/#{asset}.js" if type == :js
  end

  def asset_tag(asset, type)
    return stylesheet_link_tag asset_path(asset, type) if type == :css
    return javascript_include_tag asset_path(asset, type) if type == :js
  end

end
```

This way you can change the asset paths in any way you want and it will always be forwards compatible.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. This is a more explicit solution and is less hacky.